# Windows 7 FTP Connection Ignores File Type Associations

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, ftp, mount

I have an FTP connection active through the Map Network Drive option in Windows 7 64-bit.

When navigating the remote directory, I see no way to edit files.  Windows is completely ignoring file-type associations and "opens" everything with my default browser.

Is there any way that I can simply edit these files?

I'm open to suggestions of other software as well, but from what I can see, NetDrive doesn't work with 64-bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ability to edit/modify files as opposed to just open for reading really depends on the client software you are using. I know that EditPad Pro (www.jgsoft.com) can remotely open ftp-based files, keep a lock on the file, and re-write the files upon saving the file in the editor. The file is then released.

But FTP is not a protocol meant to support all file operations, such as locking/modifying/etc....

Personally, I prefer to first transfer the file, edit/modify it, and send it back. This ensures that each parts of the action is properly completed.

But that's my way of doing it.

Comment: Although this is a little less flexibility than I wanted, this will work.  I use NotePad++ and they've got an extension for direct FTP editing.  I like FileZilla's method for View/Edit, I just hate how I must flip back and accept the upload every single save.